# Holds no benefits to alleviate the problem

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-meaning, writing

Two people are arguing/quarrel and the arguing/quarrel they have will not alleviate the problem the already have. It is like someone telling him that stop arguing/quarrel that won't alleviate the problem.

Can I substitute "is not beneficial to" with "holds no benefits to" ?

The quarrel you both have holds no benefits to alleviate the problem.

Comment: Sorry, but neither is very good or clear English.  I'm not actually sure what you want to say.  Probably best just to cut it completely "Your quarrel will not alleviate the problem".

Comment: Two people are arguing/quarrel and the arguing/quarrel they have will not alleviate the problem the already have. It is like someone telling him that stop arguing/quarrel that won't alleviate the problem.

Comment: Where's **is not beneficial to** in the original sentence? How can it be swapped if it's not in the example sentence to begin with? If you look up the word *beneficial* in 2 or 3 dictionaries and note down the example sentences, you'll understand better how this expression is used.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing the expression "beneficial to".  You can use "beneficial" with a prepositional phrase, "exercise is beneficial to the heart". Or you can use a cleft sentence to say, "it is beneficial (to the heart) to do exercises". But you are attempting to say that something doesn't help alleviate a problem, and this isn't what "beneficial to alleviate" means.

But there is no need.  The word "alleviate" already means "get better" (or get less bad) so it already has the sense of "benefit".  So it would be good just to cut out the awkward use of "beneficial" or "benefit" and say

> <s>The quarrel you both have</s> Your quarrel won't alleviate the problem.

I've tightened up the start of the sentence.  You can also say "won't help alleviate..." to add nuance or change "alleviate" to "solve" for a slightly stronger sentence.

Comment: Thank you teacher. Both holds no benefits and is not beneficial to are the same , right? If so  is this sentence correct ( Deliver the assignment late holds no benefits to at all.) I mean if you send the homework late , the teacher won't accept it) in other words, there is no point to do so.

Comment: That sentence is completly wrong. Sorry.  You are using the word "deliver" wrong ("delivery"). and you probably mean "gives no benefits" And the use of "to at all" is also wrong. You probably mean "at all"

Comment: Your other problem is that you are trying to find a situation to use certain words, rather than find words to fit a situation.

Comment: Thank you so much. sir,  excuse for calling you (sir) teachers like you deserve the utmost respect. I guess this sentence is correct ( writing the homework quickly holds no benefits to get full mark)  right? Another question is I believe ( gives no benefits, provide no benefits, holds no benefits mean the same ,  and xxxx has no benefits right?  Thank you again

Comment: Call no man "sir".  All humans are alike in dignity. . .  James is my name. Also, in English "teacher" isn't used as a title as in "Thank you teacher".  I may be a teacher, but call me James.